# I need to find vueJs component/template file in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am working on laravel application and trying to find where from these following variables are coming so that I would customize them; As I have searched and found that these variables are coming from vueJs component file, and could not find this vueJs file as I have searched whole application's file and I have zero knowledge in vueJs. Is vueJs file is also embedded in head or before body tag as we put css and js files? please help me.

```
    <div class="row align-items-center" v-cloak>
      <div :class="item.pulse"></div>
       <div class="col ml--2">
        <small> @{{ item.last_status }}</small><br />
        <small> @{{ item.time }}</small>
         <h4 class="mb-0">
            <a href="#!"> @{{ item.id }} @{{ item.restaurant_name }}</a>
            </h4>
            <small>@{{ item.client }}</small><br />
            <small>@{{ item.price }}</small><br />
           </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
       <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" :href="item.link">{{ __('Details')}}</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Vue components are usually stored in the `resources/js/components` folder

Comment: Thank you, there is vue file but not related to these types of data, it is almost blank